# Error while installing a Python lib?

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I am trying to install the `ahocorasick` library using `easy_install` but am getting this error:

```
Searching for ahocorasick
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ahocorasick/
Reading http://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/ahocorasick/
Best match: ahocorasick 1.0pre
Downloading https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/ahocorasick/ahocorasick-1.0pre.tar.gz
Processing ahocorasick-1.0pre.tar.gz
Running ahocorasick-1.0pre\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\t-rahulp\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dmwagb\ahocorasick-1.0pre\egg-dist-tmp-c
gqixx
aho-corasick.c: In function 'aho_corasick_goto_initialize':
aho-corasick.c:171:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0x331): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\aho-corasick.o:aho-corasick.c:(.text+0x579): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\slist.o:slist.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\slist.o:slist.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\slist.o:slist.c:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\slist.o:slist.c:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\slist.o:slist.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_BuildValue'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_BuildValue'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `_imp__PyList_New'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_BuildValue'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `_imp__PyList_Append'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x237): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x252): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AssertionError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x308): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AssertionError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x32f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AssertionError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x357): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_BuildValue'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x450): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AssertionError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x45b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x479): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x4bc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x4d8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AssertionError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x4e3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x4fd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AssertionError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x508): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x537): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_MemoryError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x542): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x551): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x58f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x61b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x640): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_Ready'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x649): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_GenericNew'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x65b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_Ready'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x68c): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_InitModule4'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\py_wrapper.o:py_wrapper.c:(.text+0x6b5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_AddObject'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried doing this manually but ended up with the same error. I have MinGW added to my PATH so it should not be a problem finding `gcc`. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Find the build dependencies for `ahocorasick` and install them. You're likely missing the header and development libraries, which you can't build the program without them.

Comment: +1 Thank You. This is the project page: https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/ahocorasick/ but where can I find the dependencies? I know I am missing something trivial but can't seem to determine what I am missing.

Comment: The information seems very scarce. I can't find the build dependencies listed anywhere. :/